# Knockout Mapping plugin not working for nested objects

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following JSON data fetched from the server.

```
var viewModel=
{ 
    InvoiceOrderID:55
    orderItem :{
        OrderItemID:32
        ProductCode:45
        Name: ZipZapper
    }   
}
```

I have used `ko.mappingfromJS` on this viewModel data.
`ko.mappingfromJS(viewModel,{},self)`

Did  the `ko.applyBindings(self)` to generate the bindings

How do I databind the inner nested object's ProductCode

`orderItem().ProductCode` does not work

Comment: `orderItem` is not an observable.  You should just be able to use `orderItem.ProductCode`

Comment: On this sample data, I used the ko.mappingfromJS and so I know that orderItem is a observable now. orderItem().ProductCode does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tizzy pointed out, [knockout mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) doesn't work this way - by default it converts properties to observables and arrays to observableArrays, but nested objects are **not converted** (although their inner properties are converted to observables too).

So for your specific statement to work, your ViewModel should look like this:

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var mapping = {
        'orderItem': {
            create: function(options) {
                return ko.observable(options.data);
            }
        }
    }
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j4opjhna/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @llya luzyanin
This is exactly what I was trying to look out for.

Comment: @llya luzyanin I however have issues trying to convert the nested objects to observables. In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/p0equs3h/

You can see the inner Remarks section does not become a observable. I have used a input tag to capture the new data. On value change the Remarks data is not udpated.  How could the Remarks be made an observable ?

Comment: What issues? Remember that mapping should be done for each nesting level.

Comment: @llya luzyanin I however have issues trying to convert the nested objects to observables. In this fiddle jsfiddle.net/varunfiddle/p0equs3h You can see the inner Remarks section does not become a observable. I have used a input tag to capture the new data. On value change the Remarks data is not udpated. How could the Remarks be made an observable ?

Comment: I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0equs3h/1/). I've put mapping inside view model for the sake of correct scope + you forgot that your `userLogin` now is an observable + inside create mapping you should call ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data) to make inner properties observable.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks @llya luzyanin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) create function to tell knockout how to map your whole tree here, although I suspect you'll want a view model to represent OrderItem.

```
var OrderItemViewModel = {
   OrderItemId: ko.observable();
   ProductCode: ko.observable();
   Name: ko.observable()
}

var mapping = {
    'orderItem' : {
        create: function(data){
            return new OrderItemViewModel(data);
        }
    }
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

Comment: Yes I am in a scenario just as you have suggested. 
My class objects look this way.

public class InvoiceViewOrderModel
{

 public int InvoiceOrderID;
 public OrderItem orderItem ;

}

public class OrderItem
{
 public int OrderItemID;
 public int ProductCode;
 public string Name;
 
}

I am trying to map the InvoiceViewOrderModel which has a association to OrderItem object.

Comment: creating the mapping, and using the create function to say "when you hit this property ( orderItem ) , instantiate this other view model (OrderItemViewModel )" - should do what you need.  Then you should be able to access viewModel.OrderItem.Name()

Comment: Can't we use ko.mapping.fromJS to the nested OrderItem object also to make the process more recursive ?